# Double Lookup Values

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet used for scheduling. I have two tabs (one is **Time-Off Requests** and the other is **Scheduling**) There is a formula to match the name and selected date and return "OFFr" if the date is entered in the Time-Off Request. I've added a comments column (on Time-Off Requests) and i'm wanting to display that instead.

However, I can't get the comments to display on the sheet since it is a multiple criteria lookup for the scheduling sheet.

Criteria 1: Date from Row 8

Criteria 1: Name from Column A

I have the following formula on the **Scheduling Tab (F11)** and it works successfully. However, instead of "OFFr" I'm wanting it to display the comments from Column F on Time-Off Requests (such as "Off til 4" written in the comments column):

(side note - the formula is tied in with the perm requests "OFFp" which works as designed)

```
   =IF(ISBLANK($A9),"",IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP($A9,Table4[[Name: (Last, First)]:

[SUN]],7,FALSE)="X","OFFp",""),""))&IFERROR(IF(AGGREGATE(15, 6, 'Time-Off 

Requests'!$C$3:$C$5091/(('Time-Off Requests'!$B$3:$B$5091=$A9)*('Time-Off 

Requests'!$C$3:$C$5091=G$8)), 1)=G$8, " OFFr"), "")
```

**Time-Off Requests Tab**
[image]

**Schedule Tab**

[image]

Comment: Can you use INDEX/MATCH and just match the date to the date in your scheduling sheet?

Comment: No, as there is multiple criteria. (Match Name and Date)

Comment: You can do multiple criteria lookups with INDEX/Match.  The internet and this site have many examples of this.

Comment: What @ScottCraner said. Especially since it's one row and one column to match.